# Design pattern for organizing UIViewController transitions

Tags: ios, objective-c, design-patterns

I'm trying to come up with a good way to organize transitioning between UIViewControllers that removes the logic from the controllers themselves. I came up with a pattern based on the Pro ObjC Design Patterns book that I liked, but I'd like to know how to improve it.

The pattern in a nutshell. Forgive the semi-pseudo code.

I subclassed the UINavigation Controller and created a method that all the View Controllers call when they need to transition.

```
-(void)requestViewChangeByObject:(id)object withData:(object*)someData{

    if ([object isKindOfClass:[ViewController1 class]]) {
        [self showViewController2Animated:YES withSomeData:nil];    
    }

    if ([object isKindOfClass:[ViewController2 class]]) {
        [self showViewController3Animated:YES withSomeData:someData];
    }

    if...
}
```

Then I just defined methods for each controller. Some just instantiate and push the controller and some set properties or pass information in.

```
-(void)showViewController2Animated:(BOOL)animated withSomeData:(object*)someDataVariable{

    viewController2 *VC2 = [viewController2 defaultViewController];
    [self pushViewController:VC2 animated:animated];
}

-(void)showViewController3Animated:(BOOL)animated withSomeData:(object*)someDataVariable{

    viewController3 *VC3 = [ViewController3 defaultViewController];
    VC3.someData = someDataVariable 
    [self pushViewController:VC3 animated:animated];
}
```

The reason I'm doing it this way is because it makes the application much more flexible in terms of changing around controller order and adding/removing controllers as the design and requirements change. We also tend to re-use apps and this makes it easier to reskin and reorganize to build a new application.

The main problem I have is the more complicated the application gets the bigger that method with all the if statements is going to get. It might get confusing if there's more logic involved than just push viewController2 if the request comes from viewController3. I'd really like to know how I can improve this so that it's more flexible and less likely to cause confusion and errors.

Second, it's not very flexible when you add passing data around to the problem. I ended up taking the parameter out that accepted a data object and just created an separate singleton manager object that handles saving/getting the data that I needed, which I understand is not good design. However, when I tried passing the data back and forth between controllers like Apple suggests(ie setting properties on the controller as in the above code) it just became a confused mess and I feel like there's a better way to do this.

So any suggestions on this would be appreciated thanks.

Comment: Why reinvent the wheel? This certainly isn't how `UINavigationController` was intended for use. If you're looking at this approach to simplify your application logic perhaps it's best to refactor your application. Trial and error of refactoring is more advisable than relying on an implementation that may lead to your downfall when things start to get hairy.

Comment: If I were you, I would have my nav logic in my controllers. Even Apple's templates say in `didSelectRowAtIndexPath` that 'navigation logic would go here'.